# init NSData with NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsattributedstring

I am trying to write attributed text to a word file but I cannot init `NSData` with the type `NSDocFormatTextDocumentType`. According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSDocumentTypeDocumentOption), it is one of the many supported file types of `NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute`.

```
NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:textView.attributedText];

NSData *data = [str dataFromRange:(NSRange){0, [str length]} documentAttributes:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSDocFormatTextDocumentType} error:NULL];

//Does not work
@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSDocFormatTextDocumentType}
```

Comment: is it not supported for ios?

Comment: The `NSDocFormatTextDocumentType` is only for OSX, and in fact, these method you're trying to pull, is to fo .doc to NSAttributedString, not the reverse way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you are correct I was looking at the OSX documentation. Only 4 formats are supported for IOS.

Answer (score 0):

Larme has stated the answer in his comment. It is not supported by iOS, I was looking at the OSX version.

This is the solution I have come up with: Since Word files accept HTML as input, I converted the attributed text to HTML then wrote it in a docx file.

```
//simple code

NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:_textV.attributedText];

//convert to html then write to a .docx file to export to docx
NSData *data = [str dataFromRange:(NSRange){0, [str length]} documentAttributes:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} error:NULL];

[data writeToFile:@"/Users/myself/components/file.docx" atomically:YES];
```